# Unlimited method arguments without GC

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory-management, variadic-functions

I am trying to make a function that can receive unlimited amount of arguments without crating GC.

I know that this can be done with the `params` keyword but it creates GC. Also understand that you can pass array to to the function but I want to know if it is possible to pass unlimited method arguments *without creating GC and without creating array or list and passing it to the List*.

This is the example with the `param` code:

```
void Update()
{
    GameObject player1 = GameObject.Find("Player1");
    GameObject player2 = GameObject.Find("Player2");

    GameObject enemy1 = GameObject.Find("Enemy1");
    GameObject enemy2 = GameObject.Find("Enemy2");
    GameObject enemy3 = GameObject.Find("Enemy3");

    Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    moveObjects(newPos, 3f, player1, player2, enemy1, enemy2, enemy3);
}

void moveObjects(Vector3 newPos, float duration, params GameObject[] objs)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
    {
        //StartCoroutine(moveToNewPos(objs[i].transform, newPos, duration));
    }
}
```

When executed even with the `StartCoroutine` function commented out, it allocates **80 bytes**. At first, I thought this was happening because I used the `foreach` loop then I changed that to a `for` loop but it still creating GC then I realized that `params GameObject[]` is causing it. See the Profiler below fore more visual information on this:

[image]

So, how can I create a method that takes unlimited arguments without generating GC?

*Please ignore the use of `GameObject.Find` function used in the `Update` function. That's just used for an example to get the reference of Objects I want during run-time. I have a script implemented to handle that but not related what's in this question.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create a function with unlimited arguments without causing memory allocation.

You can do this with the undocumented `__arglist` keyword and wrapping our unlimited `params` inside it.

Change your `moveObjects(newPos, 3f, player1, player2, enemy1, enemy2, enemy3)` to `moveObjects(newPos, 3f, __arglist(player1, player2, enemy1, enemy2, enemy3))`.

In the `moveObjects` function, replace `params GameObject[] objs` with `__arglist`. Put the `__arglist` in `ArgIterator` then loop over it until `ArgIterator.GetRemainingCount` is no longer more than *0*.

To obtain each value from the arguments in the loop, use `ArgIterator.GetNextArg` to get the `TypedReference` and then `TypedReference.ToObject` to cast the `object` to the Object type passed in the parameter which is `GameObject` in your example.

The whole changes together:

```
void Update()
{
    GameObject player1 = GameObject.Find("Player1");
    GameObject player2 = GameObject.Find("Player2");

    GameObject enemy1 = GameObject.Find("Enemy1");
    GameObject enemy2 = GameObject.Find("Enemy2");
    GameObject enemy3 = GameObject.Find("Enemy3");

    Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    moveObjects(newPos, 3f, __arglist(player1, player2, enemy1, enemy2, enemy3));
}

void moveObjects(Vector3 newPos, float duration, __arglist)
{
    //Put the arguments in ArgIterator
    ArgIterator argIte = new ArgIterator(__arglist);

    //Iterate through the arguments in ArgIterator
    while (argIte.GetRemainingCount() > 0)
    {
        TypedReference typedReference = argIte.GetNextArg();
        object tempObj = TypedReference.ToObject(typedReference);

        GameObject obj = (GameObject)tempObj;
        //StartCoroutine(moveToNewPos(obj.transform, newPos, duration));
    }
}
```

While this should solve your problem, it's worth noting that it's an undocumented feature which means that it may stop working someday. If you care about that then an array should be used.

EDIT:

John Skeet mentioned about possible incompatibility on some platforms. I did a test again and it works on all the devices I tested it on. I did a test on both Windows and Android and it worked on both Windows and Android. I also expect it to work on iOS too. Too lazy to switch to Mac then fiddle with Xcode to test but there shouldn't be a problem.

**Note you must use .NET>=4.6 to get this working**

*To do that*:

**1**.Go to the Player Settings, change *Scripting Runtime Version* to *"Experimental (.Net 4.6 Equivalent)"*

**2**.Change Api Compatibility Level to *.NET 4.6*.

**3**.Change *Scripting Backend* to Mono instead of IL2CPP. IL2CPP is not supported because Unity did not implement this on it.

Comment: Note that this is for Unity3d. I would be quite surprised if it actually worked in all Unity environments, including AOT-compiled ones. It's *possible* - but I'd definitely be even more wary than normal of using a feature like this.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hello Skeet! I know that this is for Unity. I have been using this in my Unity code and it works fine.

Comment: Gosh, that does surprise me (pleasantly). I'd suggest mentioning that in your answer explicitly.

Comment: @JonSkeet I will but I want to test this again to make sure since Unity is now using new compiler. I will update the answer after the test.

Comment: @JonSkeet I did a test on both Android and Windows and it worked on Windows and Android. If I notice any platform it doesn't work on in the future, I will update this answer,

Comment: Thanks.This is what I was looking for and it worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

If you use `params` and specify arguments in that way then yes, it *will* always create an array object.

If you want to avoid that, and if you don't need to worry about recursion or thread safety, you could keep a `List<GameObject>` around and use the same list multiple times. For example:

```
private readonly List<GameObject> objectListCache = new List<GameObject>();

private void Update()
{
    cachedObjectList.Clear();
    cachedObjectList.Add(GameObject.Find("Player1"));
    cachedObjectList.Add(GameObject.Find("Player2"));
    cachedObjectList.Add(GameObject.Find("Enemy1"));
    cachedObjectList.Add(GameObject.Find("Enemy2"));
    cachedObjectList.Add(GameObject.Find("Enemy3"));

    Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    moveObjects(newPos, 3f, cachedObjectList);
    cachedObjectList.Clear();
}

void MoveObjects(Vector3 newPos, float duration, List<GameObject> objs)
{
    foreach (GameObject obj in objs)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When you clear the `List<T>` that will set all the elements of the internal buffer to null, but won't discard the buffer - so it can be used again for the next `Update` call without any allocation.

Comment: I know I can use List or array and have been doing so for a long time and also mentioned it in my question. I just don't want to create any object(list) or array to hold the arguments. This is why I asked this question. If this is the only way then I will continue to use Lis or array with a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right in front of you (Vector3). Make a super specialized `struct`:

```
public struct GameObjectParams3 // 3 only for example, you need more
{
    private int NextGet;

    public GameObject Object0;
    public GameObject Object1;
    public GameObject Object2;

    public GameObjectParams3(GameObject g0) : this(g0, null, null) { }

    public GameObjectParams3(GameObject g0, GameObject g1) : this(g0, g1, null) { }

    public GameObjectParams3(GameObject g0, GameObject g1, GameObject g2)
    {
        this.NextGet = 0;
        this.Object0 = g0;
        this.Object1 = g1;
        this.Object2 = g2;
    }

    public GameObject Next()
    {
        GameObject ret;
        switch (this.NextGet)
        {
            case 0: ret = Object0; break;
            case 1: ret = Object1; break;
            case 2: ret = Object2; break;
            default: return null;
        }
        this.NextGet++;
        return ret;
    }

    /*
    public int Length { get { return this.NextPush; } }

    private int NextPush;

    public void Push(GameObject go)
    {
        switch (this.NextPush)
        {
            case 0: Object0 = go; break;
            case 1: Object1 = go; break;
            case 2: Object2 = go; break;
            default: throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        }
        this.NextPush++;
    }
    */
}
```

And use as you use Vector3;

```
    void Update()
    {
        // ...

        var objs = new GameObjectParams3(enemy1, enemy2, enemy3);

        // Or:
        //
        // var objs = new GameObjectParams3();
        // objs.Object0 = GameObject.Find("Player1");

        // Better, make ObjectN private and:
        //
        // var objs = new GameObjectParams3();
        // objs.Push( GameObject.Find("Player1") );
        //
        // To have .Length afterwards.

        Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        moveObjects(newPos, 3f, objs);
    }

    void moveObjects(Vector3 newPos, float duration, GameObjectParams3 objs)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var obj = objs.Next();
            if (obj == null)
                return;

            //StartCoroutine(moveToNewPos(objs[i].transform, newPos, duration));
        }

        /*
        var len = objs.Length;
        for (int n = 0; n < len; n++)
        {
            var obj = objs.Next();
            StartCoroutine(moveToNewPos(objs[i].transform, newPos, duration));
        }
        */
    }
```

Comment: Title says "unlimited method arguments". What you have here is not unlimited argument. To add another one, you have to modify the GameObjectParams3  struct and add more more function and variable. In fact, adding a function overload would be better and simpler in this case

Comment: I want to be able to pass unlimited argument directly to a function not use some class, array, or list to hold them.

Comment: It's a trade off: a way to avoid a GC allocation in a platform compatible way, but not in a unlimited way. You have a call do `moveObjects` with more than 50 arguments?